# Windows: Wifi Card turns down while Shutdown Script is trggert

Tags: windows, batch-file, network-driver

I have the following problem:
When logging out of an Intel NUC connected via WLAN, a shutdown script is executed. This script is supposed to check a service, but that service is only accessible when the WLAN is enabled.
Unfortunately, the WLAN or the WLAN card is disabled during the shutdown command before the script is executed.

Is there a way to make disabling the WLAN card the last step in this process?

Comment: What's in the shutdown script?

Comment: It triggers a local service to run, basically it triggers a patchmanagement software. connected to LAN it works perfect.

Comment: ok, so disconnecting from network triggers software that depends on exactly the network you just explicitly disabled.  Bad design. I guess, you can't change the script or software, so contact your IT department and tell them there's a problem.